# Reducible representation of $SO(2)$ on $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, rotations

A representation of $SO(2)$ on $\mathbb R^3$ is the the map
$$\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta & \sin\theta\\ -\sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{bmatrix} \rightarrow\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta & \sin\theta&0\\ -\sin\theta & \cos\theta&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
This representation is reducible because when it acts on a plane of $\mathbb R^3$ it leaves the vectors on the plane.
My question is, how can I decompose this representation in a composition of irreducible representations?

Comment: You can get the proper font and spacing for $\cos$ and $\sin$ using `\cos` and `\sin`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`. Note that $\operatorname{sen}$ is a Spanish and Italian abbreviation; the standard abbreviation in English-language texts is $\sin$.

Comment: The plane and its orthogonal complement?

Comment: Because the group is compact and abelian the complexified version of this rep is a direct sum of 1-d reps. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3463996/11619).